# JQuery window scroll event not working for odoo 14

Tags: odoo

**JQuery window scroll event not working for odoo 14 **

The below code is not executed in the Odoo v14

```
`$(window).scroll(function() {
 console.log("scroll event")
});`
```

odoo v14 this event is not execute

Comment: try to use $(window).on('scroll',function(){});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution but it is only working on the first div#wrapwrap and not working with any other.

```
$('#wrapwrap').scroll(function() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked in first element inside body element with id wrapwrap too, it used by Odoo as main element

```
document.getElementById('wrapwrap').addEventListener('scroll', function () {

     console.log("scroll event")            
}, false);
```